# Storing an interface based relationship in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have this domain design idea I would like to implement. I'm using Entity Framework as the storage mechanism and the only way I can see to do so doesn't seem ideal.

I have lots of domain objects and many of them need to be "flaggable". The users need to be able to "flag" each of them as needing attention in some way.

So I thought I would create this interface:

```
public interface IFlaggable
{
    [Required]
    Tally Tally { get; }
    Guid? TallyId { get; }
}
```

and these classes:

```
public class Flag
{
    public Guid Id { get; internal set; }
    [Required]
    public Tally Tally { get; internal set; }
    public Guid TallyId { get; internal set; }
    [Required]
    public User Creator { get; internal set; }
    public Guid CreatorId { get; internal set; }
    [Required]
    public FlagIndication Indication { get; internal set; }
}

public class Tally
{
    public Guid Id { get; internal set; }
    public IFlaggable Subject { get; internal set; }
    public ICollection<Flag> Flags { get; internal set; }
}
```

FlagIndication is an enum if that's not obvious.

Then all the other domain objects have to do is implement IFlaggable and they become flaggable.

```
public class TestFlaggable : IFlaggable
{
    public Guid Id { get; internal set; }
    public Tally Tally { get; internal set; }
    public Guid? TallyId { get; internal set; }
}
```

Seems great. In terms of DB it should work just fine in that it's a one to one relationship and the other tables would always contain a foreign key to the id field of the Tallies table.

Trouble is that Entity Framework takes a look at the interface and chokes. Obviously. We know Entity Framework doesn't play well with interfaces.

The only way I can see to make it work with Entity Framework is by scrapping the interface, creating child classes such as "TestFlaggableTally" that inherit from Tally and then each other object can have it's own special snowflake Tally class.

```
public class Tally
{
    public Guid Id { get; internal set; }
    public ICollection<Flag> Flags { get; internal set; }
}

[Table("TestFlaggableTallies")]
public class TestFlaggableTally : Tally
{
    public TestFlaggable Subject { get; internal set; }
}

public class TestFlaggable
{
    public Guid Id { get; internal set; }
    public TestFlaggableTally Tally { get; internal set; }
    public Guid? TallyId { get; internal set; }
}
```

That should work but it seems silly and bloated.

So, I'm here to ask. Is there a better way?

Do I have some fundamental misunderstanding?

Is that my best option?

ok, hit me

Comment: What do you mean when you say EF chokes? I've used interfaces on my entities many times.

Comment: Just that it isn't capable of creating a relationship out of such a property. I understand why. It doesn't know where to map the thing to.

Comment: Entity Framework can't make sense of the "public IFlaggable Subject { get; internal set; }" property.

Comment: Oh I see. I haven't done this specifically. Got me interested though, going to fire up VS.

Comment: I sincerely hope you find a better way.

Comment: I am struggling with what you are trying to achieve: how do Flags and Tallies relate to one another and why should Flaggable objects have a Tally? It is no problem to have any entity implement an interface, it just is not possible to define a relation to an interface type.

Comment: A tally is just a flag collection that has some flag collection related methods and composes all that functionality for the flaggable objects. I'm aware that entity objects can implement interfaces. The relationship is the whole point.

Comment: Can't you achieve wat you want by forgoing to make `Tally` an Entity? You would then have to remove the `TallyId`foreign key from `TestFlaggable` and mark its `Tally` property as `[NotMapped]`.

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you're saying. You have to store either the TallyId in the TestFlaggable or the TestFlaggableId in the Tally or you have lost the information relating those flags to that TestFlaggable. It's a one to one relationship so you can store either one.  I have chosen to store the TallyId rather than the TestFlaggableId because it is the same regardless of the type it applies to. You have to store one of them though. I suppose I could work outside of EF create my own custom unmapped navigation properties that I would have to wire up myself but I prefer the inheritance.

Comment: I cant understand why do you need map your EF relations with interfaces. I think it would be better to map your EF entities to DTO objects and such objects can implement any interface.

Answer (score 3):

I think EF doesn't have such support for interfaces. - **NOT TRUE, SEE UPDATE**

I would suggest rewriting your interface into abstract class:

```
public abstract class FlaggableBase<T>
{
    public abstract T Id { get; internal set; }
    public abstract Tally Tally { get; internal set; }
    public abstract Guid? TallyId { get; internal set; }
}
```

Note that I added Id property to the base class, to ensure that any entity that derives from FlaggableBase has a key (EF requires this to be able to distinguish entities).

Then use it like this:

```
public class TestFlaggable : FlaggableBase<Guid>
{
    public override Guid Id { get; internal set; }
    public override Tally Tally { get; internal set; }
    public override Guid? TallyId { get; internal set; }
}

public class Tally
{
    public Guid Id { get; internal set; }
    public FlaggableBase<Guid> Subject { get; internal set; }
    public ICollection<Flag> Flags { get; internal set; }
}

public class Flag
{
    public Guid Id { get; internal set; }
    [Required]
    public Tally Tally { get; internal set; }
    public Guid TallyId { get; internal set; }
    public Guid CreatorId { get; internal set; }
}
```

The only drawback of using abstract class instead of interface I see right away, is that you will not be able to leverage lazy-loading, as you cannot apply *virtual* keyword on overrides.

If, for some reason, you still rely on the IFlaggable interface, simply implement it in the base class:

```
public abstract class FlaggableBase<T> : IFlaggable
```

**UPDATE**

I played around a bit in VS and it turns out you actually can do what you want using interfaces:

```
public interface IFlaggable<out T>
{
    T Id { get; }
    Tally Tally { get; }
    Guid? TallyId { get; }
}
```

Then in your Tally class:

```
public class Tally
{
    public Guid Id { get; internal set; }
    public IFlaggable<Guid> Subject { get; internal set; }
    public ICollection<Flag> Flags { get; internal set; }
}
```

Here's how it will look in the DB:
[image]

Comment: This does not seem to work in a collection: the collection of interface entities (IFlaggables here) never gets populated when I retrieve the Tally instance using EF.

Comment: It'd going to be populated once you make your property virtual.